# Write textbox values to XML file for each item

Tags: xml, wpf

I am trying to create XML nodes when button is clicked. The problem is when I click on save button it overrwrites the values & not generating nodes for each item. Please tell me the best & easy process to READ & WRITE textbox values to XML in **WPF**.
Please tell me what is alternative to Form_Load for **WPF**.

```
    public class SaveXML
{
    public static void SaveData(object obj, string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        XmlSerializer rs = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
        sr.Serialize(writer, obj);
        writer.Close();
    }
}

 public class Products
{
    private string DatePick;
    private string name;
    private string category;
    private string volume;
    private string volunit;
    private string quantity;
    private string purprice;
    private string sellprice;

    public Products() { }
    public Products(string DatePick, string name, string category, string volume, string volunit, string quantity, string purprice, string sellprice)
    {
        this.DatePick = DatePick;
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.volume = volume;
        this.volunit = volunit;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.purprice = purprice;
        this.sellprice = sellprice;
    }

    public string DatePicker
    {
        get {return DatePick;}
        set {DatePick = value;}
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get {return name;}
        set {name = value;}
    }

    public string Category
    {
        get {return category;}
        set {category = value;}
    }

    public string Volume
    {
        get {return volume;}
        set {volume = value;}
    }

    public string VolUnit
    {
        get {return volunit;}
        set {volunit = value;}
    }

    public string Quantity
    {
        get {return quantity;}
        set {quantity = value;}
    }

    public string PurPrice
    {
        get {return purprice;}
        set {purprice = value;}
    }

    public string SellPrice
    {
        get {return sellprice;}
        set { sellprice = value;}
    }
}
```

}`

```
private void Save_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Products product = new Products();

            product.DatePicker = Date_Picker.Text;
            product.Name = Product_Name.Text;
            product.Category = Cat.Text;
            product.Volume = Vol.Text;
            product.VolUnit = VolUnit.Text;
            product.Quantity = Quantity.Text;
            product.PurPrice = Pur_Price.Text;
            product.SellPrice = Sell_Price.Text;

            SaveXML.SaveData(product, "Data.xml");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }

    private void Main_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists("Data.xml"))
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Products));
            FileStream read = new FileStream("Data.xml", FileMode.Open,         FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            Products product = (Products)xs.Deserialize(read);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to execute xml  again & again don't want to overwrite values.I don't want my xml file to be overwritten. Any help will be greatly Appreciated.

Comment: See my comment per StreamWriter. For Loaded pay attention that it can raise more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

The `StreamWriter` constructor have an overload to specify append mode.

```
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you.